# Multiple buttons; Each one needs to display different text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, reactjs

I am trying to build upon what someone created for me and I am super new to this so be kind!

I have 9 buttons, each one displays a different image when clicked. This part is done and is working perfectly. Now I need each button to also display different text. I Can't quite get it....

So..there's this:

```
 var Form = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
  return {shirtState:'button',
  image:null,
  color:'white',
  colornotice: 'white shirt temp',
  shirtName:'',
  bandName:'',
  bandcampUrl:''}
},
handleColorChange: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  color = e.target.value
  this.setState({color: color, colornotice: color +' THIS TEXT NEEDS TO CHANGE FOR EACH BUTTON'})
},
```

The part that says "THIS TEXT NEEDS TO CHANGE FOR EACH BUTTON" is obviously what needs to change depending on which button is clicked.

And here are the buttons:

```
<div className="buttons">
          <button className="color color-white" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="white"></button>
          <button className="color color-black" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="black"></button>
          <button className="color color-blue" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="blue"></button>
          <button className="color color-green" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="green"></button>
          <button className="color color-orange" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="orange"></button>
          <button className="color color-pink" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="pink"></button>
          <button className="color color-purple" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="purple"></button>
          <button className="color color-red" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="red"></button>
          <button className="color color-yellow" onClick={this.handleColorChange} value="yellow"></button>
        </div>
```

So, each button needs to have different, predetermined text that appears in place of this snippet:

```
{this.state.colornotice}
```

The image selections that happen on each button clcik that I mentioned are determined the in CSS. That part works perfectly. Here's part of this:

```
.color-blue{
background: #fff image-url("Blue-Transparent_2300x2415.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center 0px;
background-size: cover;
```

and so on... for all 9 buttons.

Hope this makes sense. Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`props`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html):
(example with ES6 and ES7 syntax, but you will get the idea)

**Button.js**

```jsx
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class Button {
  static propTypes = {
    buttonText = PropTypes.string
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button value={this.props.buttonText}></button>
    );
  }
}
```

**Parent.js**

```jsx
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Button from './Button';

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      text: ['red', 'blue', 'orange']
    }
  }

  render() {
    let buttons = this.state.text.map(color => <Button buttonText={color} />);

    return (
      <div>
        {buttons}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I got it!

```
switch(color) {
    case 'white':
      // do this and that
      this.setState({color: color, colornotice: color +' shirt temp1'})
      break;
    case 'red':
      // do this and that
      this.setState({color: color, colornotice: color +' shirt temp2'})
      break;
    default:
      this.setState({color: color, colornotice: color +' shirt temp'})
  }
```